# Processing data row by row while bulk insert using JSON in SQl server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, insert, sql-function, table-variable

Need to Generate Tag Number While Inserting Data using JSON in SQl Server Stored Procedure.

**I have 2 Tables**
Table1: Category (lastusedIndex null in initial stage)

| Id | categoryname | assetPrefix | lastusedIndex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Keyboard | KYB | Null |
| 2 | Desktop | DTP | Null |

**Table 2: asset (Inserting data into this table)**

**It has following column**

Id, AssetTag, SerialNumber, categoryid

I am Inserting multiple records at same time, While Inserting record the **AssetTag** need to be generated automatically with asset prefix

after generating the asset tag for a item we need to increment lastUsedIndex of particular category in Category Table(Here keyboard)
or we need to increment lastUsedIndex and concatenate with assetPrefix

For Example: For key Board AssetTag would be KYB00001, KYB00002.....

Example Json Data

```
declare @Asset_Info_Json nvarchar(max)
set @Asset_Info_Json = N'[{
"SerialNumber" : "S1",
"categoryid" : "1"
},{
"SerialNumber" : "S2",
"categoryid" : "1"
}]'
exec USP_TEST @Asset_Info_Json
```

Expected output (Id auto generated)

| Id | AssetTag | SerialNumber | categoryid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | KYB00001 | S1 | 1 |
| 2 | KYB00002 | S2 | 1 |

Here is my stored procedure

```
Create procedure USP_TEST(@Asset_Info_Json varchar(max))
as
 begin
 begin transaction save_asset
 begin try


Insert into asset(AssetTag,SerialNumber,categoryid)
select  
 AssetTag = (select assetPrefix + cast(FORMAT(isnull(lastusedIndex,0) + 1,'0000#') as varchar) from category where id = CategoryId),
 SerialNumber,categoryid
From OPENJSON(@Asset_Info_Json)
WITH (SerialNumber varchar(30),categoryid varchar(30))



commit transaction save_asset
 end try
 begin catch
 rollback transaction save_asset
 end catch
end
```

Query for generate tag and update index column

```
update category set lastusedIndex = isnull(lastusedIndex,0) + 1 
OUTPUT Inserted.assetPrefix + cast(FORMAT(Inserted.lastusedIndex, '0000#') as varchar) as SerialNumber
where id = 1
```

I tried table variable but it works for single item

We cannot use custom function to generate Asset Tag because We cannot use Update statement inside function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple `AssetTag` values can be calculated using `ROW_NUMBER`.

You need to `OUTPUT` the `AssetTag` and `categoryid` into a table variable, then aggregate it back up to get the last id, in order to update the `category` table.

Because the `AssetTag` is a `varchar` column, it would be complex to have to parse the number back out. Instead you can use `MERGE` in order to `OUTPUT` columns which are not being inserted.

- You should also use locking hints on `category` to prevent concurrency issues.
- Do not messa round with `CATCH... ROLLBACK` instead just use `SET XACT_ABORT ON` which does it all for you.
- If the number of categories is small, consider changing this whole design to use `SEQUENCE` instead.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROC USP_TEST
  @Asset_Info_Json nvarchar(max)
AS

SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRAN;

DECLARE @indexes TABLE (categoryid int, NewIndex int, PRIMARY KEY (categoryid, NewIndex));

WITH source AS (
    SELECT
      j.SerialNumber,
      j.categoryid,
      c.assetPrefix,
      NewIndex = ISNULL(c.lastusedIndex, 0) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY j.categoryid ORDER BY j.SerialNumber)
    FROM OPENJSON(@Asset_Info_Json)
      WITH (
        SerialNumber varchar(30),
        categoryid varchar(30)
      ) j
    JOIN category c WITH (HOLDLOCK, UPDLOCK) ON c.id = j.categoryId
)
MERGE asset a
USING source s
ON 1=0 --never match
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT
    (AssetTag, SerialNumber, categoryid)
  VALUES
    (s.assetPrefix + FORMAT(s.NewIndex, '0000#'), s.SerialNumber, s.categoryid)
OUTPUT s.categoryid, s.NewIndex
INTO @indexes (categoryid, NewIndex)
;

UPDATE c
SET lastusedIndex = LastIndex
FROM category c
JOIN (
    SELECT
      i.categoryid,
      LastIndex = MAX(i.NewIndex)
    FROM @indexes i
    GROUP BY i.categoryid
) i ON i.categoryid = c.id;

COMMIT TRAN;
```

Comment: Can we use Triggers for update lastusedIndex ?

Comment: In theory, but it's made more complicated by the fact the tag is a string rather than just the number.